# Purpose of packStart in GTK Box development

Tags: r, gtk

I've tried to understand when the `packStart` function is useful to use but, I do not understand it. What does it do? I tried looking for the documentation but, I haven't had much luck.

Here a snip of the code I am working with.

```
# add a frame for aesthetic purposes 
frame = gtkFrameNew("Specify data location...")

window$add(frame)

# create and add a new vertical container box 
vbox = gtkVBoxNew(FALSE , 8) 

vbox$setBorderWidth(24)

frame$add(vbox)

# create a horizontal container 

hbox = gtkHBoxNew(FALSE , 8)

vbox$packStart(hbox , FALSE , FALSE , 0)

label = gtkLabelNewWithMnemonic("_File name")

vbox$packStart(label , FALSE , FALSE , 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your R bindings don't come with the GTK+ documentation, you'll need to fall back to the [regular GTK+ documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBox.html#gtk-box-pack-start) (which uses C).

`gtk_box_pack_start()` is one of the ways you can add a widget to a GtkBox. The first argument is the widget to add.

The next two arguments describe how the widget should grow when the box itself grows. They are called `expand` and `fill`, respectively. For a discussion of expanding and filling widgets, see [this](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch29s02.html).

The final argument just says how much space is between this widget and the next one you add to the container.

What they mean by *pack start* is that the widget are added in order, with the first widget appearing at the top of the box. For instance, if I do

```
vbox$packStart(widget1 , FALSE , FALSE , 0)
vbox$packStart(widget2 , FALSE , FALSE , 0)
vbox$packStart(widget3 , FALSE , FALSE , 0)
```

the box will look like

```
-------
widget1
widget2
widget3



-------
```

There are other ways to add controls to a GtkBox. `pack_end()` works similarly to `pack_start()`, except the controls are added backwards to the bottom of the box. `add()` (`gtk_container_add()`) behaves like a call to `pack_start(widget, FALSE, FALSE, 0)`); the `hexpand`/`vexpand`/`halign`/`valign` properties described on the second page I linked can be used to change the parameters later.

Good luck!